# Getting 404 not found error for service(.svc) endpoints in Asp.net web application deployed on azure app service

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service

I have a ASP.net web application in which I'm calling service endpoints like "https://webapp.azurewebsites.net/Services/DataServices.svc/GetSalesOrders" to retrieve data and do CRUD operations.
This app works fine on my localhost but when I deployed it on azure web service, all the "../DataServices.svc/.." calls are giving 404 not found error. I'm not sure how to resolve this, can anyone please help?
This is my web.Config file

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="connectionstring" />
    
    <add key="RecordsPerPage" value="20" />
    <add key="ServiceUrl" value="http://portal.azurewebsites.net/Services/DataServices.svc/" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="36000" maxRequestLength="1023750" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="DashBoard.aspx" loginUrl="login.aspx" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>  

    <services>
      <service name="ProjectName.Services.DataServices">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ProjectName.Services.IDataServices" behaviorConfiguration="restfulbehaviour" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulbehaviour">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
                <clear />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                <add name="X-Powered-By" value="ASP.NET" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="login.aspx" />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
      </files>    
    </defaultDocument>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <add path="*">
                    <traceAreas>
                        <add provider="ASP" areas="" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ASPNET" areas="AppServices,Infrastructure,Module,Page" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="ANCM,Authentication,Cache,CGI,Compression,FastCGI,Filter,Module,RequestNotifications,RequestRouting,Rewrite,Security,StaticFile,WebSocket" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    </traceAreas>
                    <failureDefinitions statusCodes="500" />
                </add>
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing>
   </system.webServer>
 <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>  
             <webServices>                                                   
                 <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644" />                 
             </webServices>
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: what is the exact URL for which you are getting the 404 error? did you try to hit it via browser or postman? check if you are giving the correct url for your published web app.

Comment: Please refer [404 response code caused by App Services](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/404-response-code-caused-by-app-services-alwayson-feature/)

Comment: Specify the security mode in the webHttpBinding tag. ***<security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType = "None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
            </security>***

Comment: Hi @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT, I added <security mode="Transport"> <transport clientCredentialType = "None" proxyCredentialType="None"/> </security> and my webHttpBinding is now looking like 
 <webHttpBinding>
      <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
          <security mode="Transport"> <transport clientCredentialType = "None" proxyCredentialType="None"/> </security>
      </binding>
</webHttpBinding>

Now the site is not opening and showing "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request."

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, turns out it was due to SSL. My app was built for http and settings of Azure AppService was configured for https, that's why I was getting 404.